# A similar term to "paga fantas"

Tags: difference, idioms, colloquial-language

In my country, we use the informal term **"paga fantas"** which refers to a man who buys stuff or is willing to get anything for a girl with the intent of seducing her.

In some particular cases, a man who does this only intends to have sex with a girl, therefore he makes a great effort to buy a girl expensive stuff so that she accepts having sex with him.

Having said that, the purport of **"paga fantas"** doesn't refer to the following English terms:

Don Juan,
Lothario,
Prince Charming,
Cocksman,
Ladies' man,
Lady-killer,
Philanderer,
Playboy,
Seducer,
Sheik,
Womanizer,
Philander, 
Skirt-chaser.

I would appreciate your valuable help in advance.

Comment: The Wiktionary definition of pagafanta is rather different: a person who pays for a girl's drinks, but doesn't get close to forming a relationship.  It gives the slang term "orbiter" as a translation.  Is this close to what you are asking?

Comment: @JamesK In the [duplicate question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222096), OP does seem to indicate that a term representing the Wiktionary definition is sought.

Answer (score 3):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pagafantas) gives the translation "[orbiter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orbiter)", *"A person who constantly hangs around with someone they are attracted to, but too shy to talk to."*

Alternatively, if I have misunderstood, a "[Sugar daddy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sugar_daddy)" is typically an older man who buys gifts for a younger woman. *"A man who spends money for the benefit of a relationship with an often younger romantic or sexual partner."*

Answer (score 1):

A term that comes to mind is ***nice guy***. In most contexts, it simply means a guy who is literally nice. It is something both males and females would most often use to praise someone — *It's great to be working with him; he's such a nice guy.*

"Nice" can have negative connotations, however, indicating someone who is not assertive or ruthless enough, and who therefore will not succeed, or who might be gullible or easily exploited. This gives rise to expressions like *[no more Mr. Nice Guy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Mr.%20Nice%20Guy)* and *[nice guys finish last](https://mentalfloss.com/article/62774/where-does-phrase-nice-guys-finish-last-come)*.

In pop culture discussion of relationships, a "[nice guy](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/love-sex/nice-guy-syndrome-dating-tactics-persona-men-women-relationships-a7476651.html)" is archetypically a man who is unable to articulate his romantic interest in a woman (especially from insecurity about his attractiveness), and who overcompensates by being overtly generous and accommodating, in the hopes that the subject of his attention will notice, return the interest, and take the initiative in advancing a relationship. This is not how adult human relationships actually work, of course, but that does not stop the nice guy from constantly making gestures.

The English title of the 2009 Spanish film *[Pagafantas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1161443/)* is *Friend Zone*, which may also be a helpful related concept to know.

In pop culture, the ***[friend zone](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-attraction-doctor/201302/avoiding-the-friend-zone-becoming-girlfriend-or-boyfriend)*** is an imaginary space in which someone is stuck when he or she has a romantic interest in someone, and that second person does not reciprocate that interest—but that second person is willing to maintain a non-romantic friendship. If the second person wanted to have no contact, the first person would be forced to move on. In the friend zone, however, the first person maintains the non-romantic relationship in the desperate hope the situation will change.

*Nice guy* and *friend zone* were relatively lighthearted phrases until relatively recently. Now, as with so much else, they have been weaponized by extremists on both the right and the left, so if you are writing anything going on the Internet, be prepared for a torrent of abuse.